# How do I share a raw pointer across threads in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've got a pointer from a C++ library that I have protected by `Arc<Mutex<_>>` in order to be able to share it between threads, but the compiler is still saying it is not `Send+Sync`.

Here is a minimal example:

```rust
use std::{
    ffi,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

struct Wrapper {
    ptr: *mut ffi::c_int,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello {}", *self.ptr)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut inner: ffi::c_int = 0;
    let wrapper = Wrapper { ptr: &mut inner };

    let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(wrapper));

    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        arc.lock().unwrap().hello();
    });
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut i32` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:22:24
    |
22  |       std::thread::spawn(|| {
    |  _____------------------_^
    | |     |
    | |     required by a bound introduced by this call
23  | |         Arc::into_inner(arc).unwrap().lock().unwrap().hello();
24  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut i32` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Wrapper`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut i32`
```

Why does `Arc<Mutex<_>>` not allow me to share my pointer across threads?

Comment: Pointers are not `Send` or `Sync` so you have to wrap the pointer in a struct which unsafely implements them to inform the compiler that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Isn't this the problem that Arc+Mutex is supposed to solve though?

Comment: Mutex will make a `Send + !Sync` type `Send + Sync`. Since pointers aren't `Send`, `Mutex<*mut _>` is `!Send + !Sync`. There is nothing that can safely make a non-`Send` type `Send`, other than a wrapper that does `unsafe impl Send`. (`Arc` is orthogonal to the discussion; it provides shared ownership.) See [Send and Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html) and particularly pay attention to the parts about pointers.

Answer (score -1):

no you can not. `Rust` has been removed which in my opinion is one of the dumbest things in `c++`

a `message channel` hack would have the same result

```rust
use std::{
    ffi,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

struct Wrapper {
    ptr: *mut ffi::c_int,
}

unsafe impl Send for Wrapper {}
unsafe impl Sync for Wrapper {}

impl Wrapper {
    fn hello(&self) {
        unsafe {
            println!("Hello {}", *self.ptr);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut inner: ffi::c_int = 0;
    let wrapper = Wrapper { ptr: &mut inner };

    let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(wrapper));

    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        arc.lock().unwrap().hello();
    });
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: "Rust has been removed which in my opinion is one of the dumbest things in c++" - I feel like there are some missing words here. Can you clarify?

Comment: Rust definitely allows that, see the duplicate.